# React TSX render method return type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, react-component

I'm rewriting a react class component with tsx. I'm using quite a strict eslintrc file with lots of recommended settings:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-var": 1,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "error",
      {
        "allowTypedFunctionExpressions": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"]
}
```

With this configuration I get the following error "Missing return type" on my render method in typescript:

[image]

I can add JSX.Element as the return type, but was wondering because shouldn't that already be known to typescript because the class extends `React.Components`?

I made sure I have all the types installed.

Also, do you think my eslintrc makes sense for production?

I appreaciate all the help!

Comment: Yes.. But as I wrote, shouldn't the return type already be known to Typescript because I extend the React.Component Class. I'm calling the render method not creating it...

Comment: Ah okay, no it's in the code. It's a very large component so I only screenshotted the error part. I'm returning a JSX Element.